# Merge ignoring type errors: length, and type mismatch

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My query is an extension of the below thread

[PostgreSQL equivalent of Oracle LOG ERRORS clause in MERGE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761838/postgresql-equivalent-of-oracle-log-errors-clause-in-merge-statement)

I understand that Postgressql does not provide an option to route the errors during a massive DML, but is there an alternate solution to handle the errors.

I have a requirement to INSERT/UPDATE 100k records into a table and if there are errors with one record, then the whole transaction gets rolled back. I just need to skip the error records(ex: datatype mismatch or data length exceeds the target column length) and continue with the rest of the load. I considered LOOP and its an expensive operation.

Comment: Upgrade to >=9.5 and you have `UPSERT` in the form of [`INSERT … ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

> route the errors

Not sure what you even mean there.

> I have a requirement to INSERT/UPDATE 100k records into a table and if there are errors with one record, then the whole transaction gets rolled back. I just need to skip the error records(ex: datatype mismatch or data length exceeds the target column length) and continue with the rest of the load. I considered LOOP and its an expensive operation.

There is no other way to work with such data other than with a loop,

- On the server, that loop can be written with a cursor that catches errors. You can run [`RAISE [debug|notice]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) as permitted in plpgsql. Or, you can call `NOTIFY` and alert a daemon.
- On the client, you can verify that the data meets your constraints and stream it in with an appropriate `COPY FROM STDIN`. Because you're writing the code to skip invalid rows you can handle the error however you want.

Answer (score 0):

If applicable, you can create a function and use `EXCEPTION` control statement. Once we had an issue like "log any error in particular log table while executing a statement and continue without error" so we used something like this;

```
DO
$body$
DECLARE
  l_pg_exception_detail text;
  l_pg_exception_hint text;
  l_pg_exception_context text;
BEGIN
  --insert / update / delete statement here
  INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_pg_exception_detail = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL;
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_pg_exception_hint = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_pg_exception_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;

      RAISE NOTICE 'something happened: DETAIL: % , HINT: % , CONTEXT: % ', 
        l_pg_exception_detail,
        l_pg_exception_hint,
        l_pg_exception_context;
END;
$body$
```

Documentation reference is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)